# REST/JSON with images and objects: Multi form or pure JSON

Tags: json, html, forms, rest

My HTML5 application needs to send (small) images + objects to my backend.
What is the best solution ? :

**Solution1:** Send a multi form with 2 parts (JSON string for objects + image form for images)

**Solution2:** Send a simple JSON message including object + image as data:uri

Can you please help me to find pro/cons of the 2 solutions ? or propose an new solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using form data to pass data to the server (i.e. using multipart/form-data) because that's the standard HTML uses. If the data needs to be in JSON format, then you can convert it in the server side. If you need to pass JSON objects, then you can use a string as a key and the JSON string as the value.

The consequence of using the data URI scheme is that images are encoded into a string, making it longer, thus the client needs to pass more data.